# How to add a custom email verification for firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to change the default email verification and password reset to my custom email without having to change the link in which the user has to go to. I added the domain I want to and did the necessary changes to the domain. Waited 48 hours to verify, the response was that it cannot be verified. I would like to have more details on how to add a custom email.

Comment: talked to firebase support and they helped me fix it.